# Will ngwebdriver with appium for iOS app testing works?

Tags: angularjs, appium

We have a Cordova angular mobile app on which we are trying to achieve automation testing and as team is not familiar with javascript -trying to avoid using protractor tool.  Instead can we use ngWebDriver with appium and selenium with testng framework

Comment: Sure you can. It's probably legal. As to whether you should or what other options there are: that makes this question a matter of personal preferences, which is off-topic here. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It should work too. You can use xpath although it may have performance hit